# Untar multiple files in separate sub directories

Tags: linux

I have assignment directory containing folder for each student.
Each folder contains the studentname.tar.gz submission file.
I have 100 such submissions.
Assignment/
S1/s1.tar
S2/s2.tar
How do I untar them all with command line or script in the same folder as the student's ?

Answer (score 3):

Something along the lines of

```
for D in Assignment/*; do
  test -d "$D" || continue
  tar -C "$D" -xf "$D/"$(basename "$D")".tar"
done
```

should do the trick.

If these are .tar.gz (and not .tar) files you will want `-xzf`